# How to get information from my Android Fragment to MyActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to learn to create an Android fragment to implement an amount insert box which I can reuse throughout my application. So I create a simple xml file which has some EditText boxes. I then created the associated java file called AmountFragment.java:

```
public class AmountFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.amount_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I then use this fragment in another xml file:

```
<fragment 
    android:name="com.example.android.ui.widget.AmountFragment"
    android:id="@+id/transaction_amount"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

This works fine so far. It shows the fragment fine and I can insert numbers in it. I now want to be able to get the inserted text in the mainActivity. So I read [this page on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) from the Android docs, but I'm totally lost. The code they show makes no sense at all to me. I need to define an interface, but I have no clue what I have to do with it. I tried simply copy-pasting it over, but I get an InflateException. Since I don't even know what's going on I have no clue where to look for a solution.

So my question: can anybody give me some pointers on how to interface this fragment with the Activity in which I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

In `MainActivity.java` add

```
public void getMessage(Object obj) {
    Log.d("My App", "Look at my object " + obj.toString();
}
```

That will get objects from your `AmountFragment`, then in your `AmountFragment` write:

```
String anyObject = "Yay something";
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMessage(anyObject);
```

What's happening here is that `getActivity()` will get the instance of the `Activity` which contains the fragment, then you cast it to your activity, `MainActivity`, and call the receiver method you wrote for it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! That indeed works perfect. Another thing though; I of course want to get the result of the EditText to the MainActivity. So I tried `EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);`, but then it complaints that the method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type AmountFragment. Any idea how how I could get the result of a specific EditText to the mainActivity when I click a submit button in the xml of the MainActivity?

Comment: Similar fix there. `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.amount)` will work. Also if this fixed the issue for you, mark it as correct for other people when they come to this question. Thanks.